# JDBC to PostgreSQL Not working since upgrading Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, jdbc

So I had PostgreSQL working in Ubuntu 11.04 using 8.4(?), however, when I upgraded it also upgraded PostgreSQL to 9.1 and now I can't connect using JDBC.

I added the following to my pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

and the following to my postgres.conf...

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

but I get the following connecting with SQuirrel

```
My Local PostgresSQL: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is a better fit for http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Sounds like your server is not started. Can you connect using psql?

Comment: Yes I can connect using sudo -u postgres psql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-postgres.html) the default port is `5432`, however, per the `postgres.conf` file that came installed by default the port is set to `5433`...

```
port = 5433
```

So if someone else has this problem try the new port.

I think it has to do with the install incrementing the port when it sees the existing `8.4`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a IPv4 vs IPv6 issue? Try adding this line

```
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

and try connecting to the hostname `localhost`.

If that's not a solution, please try `md5` instead of `trust` and give the connecting user a password. Just to be sure to rule this out.

Comment: _host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5_ already exists in the file. I tried making it trust, and I also tried making the other one md5 no dice, thanks though.

Comment: Will post in 6 hours (freaking rule!) but here is the answer FYI Per [this site](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-postgres.html) the default port is 5432, however, per the postgres.conf file that came installed by default the port is set to 5433...

    port = 5433

So if someone else has this problem try the new port.